# Parsing Childnode values in javascript

Tags: javascript, nodes, htmlcollection

I have an XML

```
<root><example><examplevalue>exampletext</examplevalue><examplevalue>exampletext2</examplevalue</example></root>
```

and I have the following javscript code

```
            if (window.DOMParser){ // Standard browsers
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
            }
            else { // Internet Explorer
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString); 
            }
            var coll=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("example");
            console.log(coll[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

The console output is

```
null
```

I would expect it to be

```
exampletext
```

Why are the childnodes not parsed correctly?
childNodes seems to be a method of class node. But the getElementByName return a HTMLCollection object. How does that work?
Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

It because you fell into `window.DOMParser` condition. For `DOMParser` you need to use `textContent`.

In your case, you can create a function called `getNodeValue` and pass the node. Then get which one is available.

```js
const getNodeValue = (node) => node.nodeValue || node.textContent;

 if (window.DOMParser){ // Standard browsers
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString); 
}
var coll=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("example");
console.log(getNodeValue(coll[0].childNodes[0]))
// output => examplecontent
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to navigate to it using the `childNodes` property to access the value of the first `<examplevalue`> element then access its `textContent` property

```
if (window.DOMParser) { // Standard browsers
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString); 
}

var exampleValues = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("examplevalue");
console.log(exampleValues[0].textContent);
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference the examplevalue-elements in the context of the parent element "example"? I would like to search for certain values in one examplevalue-element and , if found, dump all examplevalue-element of the current "example"-parent element